# Azure Mobile Service PullSync query for Android Native

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

Kindly help me to rewrite below mentioned Query in Android Native Application.

```
await mantraTable.PullAsync("mantrastest", mantraTable.Where(c => 
(c.LanguageMappingIDs.Contains("16") || c.LanguageMappingIDs.Contains("18")) 
&& (c.LocationMappingIDs.Contains("30") || 
c.LocationMappingIDs.Contains("32"))));
```

Above Query is written in Xamarin Android and LanguageMappingIDs and LocationMappingIDs contains the comma (,) separated values in one column Ex: 16,15,18, 24,30,58

Thank you...Mobile platform is Android Native.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? What steps have you already taken to solve this problem yourself? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying

Comment: query=((QueryOperations.subStringOf(QueryOperations.val("30"),QueryOperations.field("LocationMappingIDs") ).or(QueryOperations.subStringOf(QueryOperations.val("32"), QueryOperations.field("LocationMappingIDs"))) ).and(QueryOperations.subStringOf(QueryOperations.val("16"),QueryOperations.field("LanguageMappingIDs") ).or(QueryOperations.subStringOf(QueryOperations.val("18"), QueryOperations.field("LanguageMappingIDs"))) ));
Above query is not filtering as per the requirement, or/and condition is not doing their job (means, getting unwanted result, exatra rows), tried with all the possibilities